# Accessing a std::array via a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14

This is just for learning purposes, I know I can just use a vector but I have

```
const int N = 1e3;
auto my_arr = std::make_unique<std::array<int, N>>();

// To access it I have to do this - why [0][0] twice?
my_arr.get()[0][0] = 1;

// Getting the size for fun
std::cout << sizeof(my_arr.get()) << "\n"; // outputs 8
std::cout << sizeof(my_arr.get()[0]) << "\n"; // outputs 800000000
std::cout << sizeof(my_arr.get()[0][0]) << "\n"; // outputs 8
```

I understand that .get() returns a pointer to the managed object but I don't understand why I need to do `my_arr.get()[0][0]` twice?

Comment: `my_arr.get()` returns a pointer. Dereferencing a pointer and indexing it at position 0 are the same thing.  `ptr[0]` is defined to be the same at `*(ptr + 0)`

Comment: `my_arr.get()[0]` is the same as `*(my_arr.get())`. You should use the latter because there's no `my_arr.get()[1]`.

Comment: Are you actually sure about _`const int N = 1e3;`_? That looks kind of weird. Also remember that `std::unique_ptr` is a replacement for a pointer, so strictly speaking you'll get a pointer to a pointer decayed from an array, and you'll end up with more or less `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @n.m. actually op should use `*my_arr` without get

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ what looks weird about it?

Comment: @JackEvans why don't you simply use a strict `size_t` type literal rather than that uncanny cast from a `double` literal?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I hadn't even thought of what was happening there, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you don't have to do that, but it works.

`my_arr.get()` returns a `std::array<int,N>*`

Like any pointer, you can index it like an array.

`my_arr.get()[0]` returns a reference to the first element in your 'array' of arrays.

You can then use `std::array`'s indexing operator to get an element.

`my_arr.get()[0][0]` returns a reference to the element you want.

Alternatively, you could write:

```
my_arr->at(0)
my_arr->operator[](0)
(*my_arr)[0]
*my_arr->data()
```

Comment: Thanks for providing those alternatives, they were very helpful

Answer (score 7):

`my_arr.get()` gives you a `std::array<int, N>*`.  Since you have a pointer doing `pointer[0]` is the same as `*pointer`.  So you don't actually need `my_arr.get()[0][0]` and you can instead use

```
(*my_arr.get())[0]
```

to show that you are dereferencing the pointer.  In fact, you could just use

```
(*my_arr)[0]
```

because `operator *` is overloaded for `std::unique_ptr` and it will return a reference to the pointed to thing.

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't want to do this:

```
auto my_arr = std::make_unique<std::array<int, N>>();
```

Unless you *really specifically* want an `array<int, N>`. If what you just want to do is dynamically allocate `N` `int`s and manage that with a `unique_ptr`, that's:

```
auto my_arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(N);
```

The advantages here are:

- `N` can be a runtime value, it doesn't have to be a constant-expression.
- [`unique_ptr<T[]>::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at) exists and does what you want, so `my_arr[2]` does index into the array.

Answer (score 3):

As you said yourself `.get()` returns a pointer to the managed object.

So it is `std::array<int, N>*` what you return and not `std::array<int, N>`:

```
std::array<int, N>* array_ptr = my_arr.get();
```

So either write `(*my_arr)[0]`  or `(*my_arr.get())[0]`